# Can z/VSE expose data via SOAP/REST?

Tags: ibm, mainframe

I work for a large organization still using an IBM mainframe on z/VSE 5.1.

Today we interact with the system over flat files exclusively  (to get data out of the system or pass data in).

Does anyone have experience exposing data in another manner? Flat files are a drag and querying directly against the mainframe would be ideal.

Comment: Is the data in VSAM? If so, look into z/VSE Connectors. I also check with the VSE-L mailing list and IBM's z/VSE web site. You can also send me a private message if you don't feel comfortable in giving more detail in a public forum.